# swipl: how to reload file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

First I load the file with `SWI-Prolog`

```
$ swipl file.pl
```

then I modify the file and save.

Now how do I reload the file like

```
?- reload
```

for this modified `file.pl`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

SWI-Prolog has a predicate `make/0` for this purpose:

```
?- make.
```

Note that SWI-Prolog has a handy feature for searching the manual for keywords:

```
?- apropos(reload).
```

Points you (among other things) to Section 3.3 of the manual: "The test-edit-reload cycle", which mentions this.

Answer (score 4):

[*Make*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/make.pl) will reload all source files that have been changed since they were loaded, but if you need to reload an specific file you can use *[reload_file](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=make%3Areload_file/1)*:

```
?- make:reload_file(source_file).
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I keep coming back here looking for is in the Windows/Emacs environment of SWI Prolog, after editing a file `Ctrl-S` to save it and `Ctrl-C Ctrl-M` inside the editor to trigger the reload.

NB. it does not work in the toplevel, where Ctrl-C triggers an interrupt.

From the [editreload](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=editreload) section in the manual mentioned by Isabella Newbie's answer.